# How to map the surface of a sphere to the surface of a Klein bottle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

## Background:

There are those "infinite puzzles" that map the view of our galaxy to the surface of a Klein bottle (https://n-e-r-v-o-u-s.com/blog/?p=7613) or a real projective plane (https://n-e-r-v-o-u-s.com/blog/?p=8068). To my understanding the original image is a 360 degrees view of our galaxy. So that is equivalent to an image on the inner surface of a sphere.

## My Question:

What I can't understand: How do you map such an image to the surface of a Klein bottle or a real projective plane without getting any artifacts (like the image is not correctly tiling)?

Did I misunderstood anything?
Did they used any tricks?

**Beware:** I have no real knowledge about topology, so please try to use common language in any explanation. (As I am not sure which tag fits best, I also added multiple "similar sounding"(to my ears))

Comment: First, you must understand how the square representation  is an accurate depiction of the KB or the $\Bbb P^2$. Then you have to imagine (I can’t!) how the puzzle can be constructed so that the pieces along the right and left edges match up properly; also the top and bottom edges.

Comment: I understand how the KB or P² can be represented by a square. I mean it's just the gluing diagram. And to constructing puzzle piezes that interfere correctly: I think you can just grow them on the surface of a KB or P².

Comment: Are you sure they are claiming a map (in the mathematical sense) of a sphere to another surface (a torus or Klein bottle)? There is not map like that which would not destroy local topology somewhere. In contrast, sphere does cover the projective plane, so you get a "nice" map in this case. This map amounts to identifying opposite point on the sphere. Of course, this will not work with Hubble photos. My guess is that they cut the actual photo into small pieces and, since many parts of the photo are empty they can do whatever they want in those areas.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm not sure. I'm just judging from what they say on their website.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mistakenly sent the unfinished comment. here is the rest:
- The KB puzzle uses this <https://web.archive.org/web/20160310102204/http://hubblesite.org/newscenter/archive/releases/2009/28/image/b/format/xlarge_web/> image. They glue the right and the left edge together so that it forms a kind of zylinder. but they still flip the pieces when taking it from one to the other edge (How does one map that to a klein bottle?) I can't see what they are doing with the top and bottom edge.
- To the P² puzzle: how does one map a sphere to a P²?

Comment: Ok, this is not a full spherical view, so they are cheating, of course. (How else can one run a successful business?) Notice that except for  a part of the bottom, most of the boundary of the image is empty, so one can cut and paste in arbitrary fashion, the user will not notice. What do they do with the bottom I do not know.